# Issue On Listing Woocommerce Parent Tag List

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, woocommerce-offtopic

I am having some issue on getting top level terms of `product_cat` Taxonomy of WooCommerce
First of all I have a code which list all Terms in `product_cat`  as:

```
$terms = get_terms("product_cat");
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

[Result Here](http://rumioptical.com/listterms/)

This basically list all Terms of Taxonomy (`product_cat`). bet what I need is listing Top Level of this list so I used this code to list First Level of the terms hirachy:

```
$terms = get_terms("product_cat",'parent=0');
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

As you can see I passed the `'parent=0'` parameter to get the top level list but I am only getting One while I am sure I at least have 4 more like Designer Eyeglasses , and Contact Lenses..

[Result Here](http://rumioptical.com/test/)

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can get the top level list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) does exactly what it says, it retrieves all terms of the specified taxonomy

> Retrieve the terms in a taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

There are a couple of functions that you can make use of here. You nedd to follow the links, each functions is well documented with examples. You just need to choose the one that fits your needs best

- [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)
- [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)
- [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)
- [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)